# React - Highlighting selected row in a table

Tags: reactjs

I have a small component that renders out some table rows. I want to highlight when a row is selected. I have the following code...

```
import Styles from "../styles/MailSummary.module.scss";

const MailSummary = ({ id, from, subject, date }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();

  const setActiveRow = (id) => {
    setActive(id);
  };

  return (
    <tr
      className={`${Styles.rowHover} ${active === id ? Styles.selected : ""}`}
      onClick={() => {
        setActiveRow(id);
      }}
    >
      <td>{from}</td>
      <td>{subject}</td>
      <td>{date}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default MailSummary;
```

This works fine when selecting a row but selecting other rows also changes the CSS class so I have multiple selected rows. I think can see why it isn't working but I'm not sure on the correct approach on how to resolve this. I may be missing something super obvious. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the state out of this component and into it's parent. Because every MailSummary now has it's own active state. You want one state, so you can move the state to the parent component and give every MailSummary a *active* prop and then add class based on *active* prop.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-lalande-rowbh?file=/src/App.js